# How to host multiple sites on Azure web app for Containers using docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-for-containers

I would like to use a docker compose file to deploy multiple public end points for our Linux hosted site.

We already have a deployed site that has images stored on a private ACR and is hosted on an Azure App Service (using Web App for Containers).  It is deployed via Azure DevOps and works well.

We would however, like to use the same site to host an additional component, an api so that we would then end up with these endpoints:

- https://www.example.com -  the main site
- https://www.example.com/api - the api

We would like to avoid a second app service or a subdomain if possible. The architecture we prefer is to use the same https certificate and ports (443) to host the api.  The web site and api share a similar code base.

In the standard app service world, we could easily have deployed a virtual directory to the main app which is simple enough.

This model though seems to be more complicated when using containers.

How can we go about this? I've already had a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app.  However, in this example, the second container is a private one - which doesn't get exposed.

Should we use a docker compose file (example please)?  Or alternatively, is there a way we can use the Azure DevOps task to deploy to a viritual directory in the way that i would like.  This is the task we are using for the single container deployment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-containers?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirements, the Web App For Container is also a type of Web App service, and as you see, it only can expose one container to the outside(the Internet) and others are private. So if you want to use the multi-containers Web App to deploy the images to access multiple endpoints such as the main site and the API site, then it's impossible to make your purpose come true.

According to the feature of the Web App that it only exposes one container to the outside, what you can do to achieve your purpose is that creates only one image and route to the endpoints yourself in the code or through a tool, such as the Nginx. Then deploy it to the Web App for Container. Only in this way, you can access multiple endpoints from only one App service..

Comment: @ossentoo Glad that's helpful!